# sed replace string with space and special characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The test23 file contains a line

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
```

I need to replace this with

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana
```

This below steps in the script doesn't work.

```
line_old='root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/'
line_new='root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana'
sed -i "s/\${line_old}\/\${line_new}/\g" test23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing delimiter of sed:

```
sed -i "s|${line_old}|${line_new}|g" test23
```

**example**

```
echo "${line_old}" | sed "s|${line_old}|${line_new}|g"
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
sed '/^root_url[ ][=]/s/$/grafana/' filename
```

Where:

- `/^root_url[ ][=]/` locates the line beginning with `"root_url ="`, then
- the normal substitution form `'s/$/grafana/'` simply appends "grafana" to the end of the line.

(**note:** add `-i` to edit the file in-place, or add `-i.bak` to edit in-place preserving a copy of the original file unchanged in `filename.bak`)

**Results**

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana
```

Look things over and let me know if that meets your needs and if you have any questions.